# Error in PHP Select Statement

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to php and am having some difficulty accessing content from a MySQL db. I converted an old MS Access DB using bullzip.com's conversion tool and was able to successfully import the tables/data into my MySQL db. I seem to be able to connect to the db as I get the "Connection Successful" message I ask for in my script. I have confirmed that "waitlist" is the correct spelling for an existing table with 24 records yet I am not successful in returning data to $result. I have this hosted online and have verified that username used in the script has full privileges to the database. I'm at a loss as the script seems very simple. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php
    $servername = "sampleserver.com";
    $username = "MyUserName";
    $password = "MyPassword";
    $dbasename = "DatabaseName";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbasenamne);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) 
    {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    ELSE {
        echo("Connection Successful");
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM waitlist";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    IF ($result)
        echo("<p>true");
    {
        echo ("<p>false");
    }
?>
```

Comment: So you currently get `<p>false`? Check what `$result` is and use error reporting on it.

Comment: what's your output?

Comment: Once you `query('SELECT...')` you must then `fetch` the result rows. For example read [The manual, strange as that may seem](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

Comment: Output is false

Comment: So you need to check for errors, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php, to know why.

Comment: That `IF` statements looks, pardon the pun, iffy! The curly braces are wrong to my eye

Comment: Chris, I'm obviously new to php. Returning the errors was the key. Probably the most important thing I learned today. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you have a syntax error where true and false would both get printed.

try this:

```
if ($result){
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo $row['id'];
    }
} else {
  echo $conn->error;
}
```

Comment: Yes. This was sloppy and made it tougher to find the error.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you misspelled `$dbasename`, secondly, you didn't wrap your `if($result)` block with an `else` block

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbasename = "test";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbasename);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) 
    {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    else {
        echo("Connection Successful");
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if($result)
        echo("<p>true");
    else
        echo ("<p>false");
?>
```

Comment: Thank you. The misspelling was the root of the problem, and I complicated it with the poorly formatted if statement. I appreciated the help.